# Can't get objects inside of array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have been trying to use JavaScript array to push my object by header
like this :

```
var tab_temp = new Y.TabView(
  { srcNode: '#' + tabId }
);
tabsArray['"' + type + "_" + subTypes + '"'] = tab_temp;
```

Let's `type = "x"` and `subTypes = "y"`, so I was expecting the object when I write something like:

```
tabs["x_y"]
```

But there is problem with this. When I debug, I can see this array will hold an object `"x_y"` but length of the array is `0`

[image]

I can't use push also because in that way I need to use index to get it back but it is tough since sequence might change.

Edit 1:

I am using this because I want to hold a couple of TabView objects. Otherwise I can't reach those object after they created. (AlloyUI). I was able to push those object inside of array. As you see `"Baru_BARANG"` include and object that start with: `s`

Edit 2:

Thanks for help, I fixed it. I used `Object` instead of `Array` for this:

```
var tabs = {}
tabs[x + "_" + y] = "z";
```

I get the value by `tabs[x + "_" + y]`

Comment: how are you initialising your `tabsArray`?

Comment: can u paste your full code please , are u initiallize the array ? and do u use push or assigning the values to the array

Comment: The `.length` of the array is `0` though you should still be able to access variable using `tabs["x_y"]`; consider substituting using an object instead of an array

Comment: @mauris it is global variable so i can reach from another function, it is a picture taken in another function. So I can see object but can't reach.

Comment: @guest271314 I couldn't.

Comment: @SahinYanlık Try `var tabsArray = [];

var x = "x", y = "y";

tabsArray[x + "_" + y] = 123; console.log(tabsArray["x_y"])`. Note, `tabsArray.length` will still be `0`. To set `.length` you can use `for..in` loop `var i = 0; for (var prop in tabsArray) {tabsArray.length = ++i}; console.log(tabsArray.length)`; though you should probably use an `Object` to set property names, values

Comment: Why do you need the length?

Comment: `length` is `0` because the array doesn't have any elements. Only properties with a positive integer property name are considered elements. You are abusing arrays as a map. Don't do that. You can use `Map` instead. And as @torazaburo mentions, it seems you are confused about strings too. The quotation marks of a string *literal* are not part of the *value*. `"x_y"` and `'"x_y"'` (which is what you get with `'"' + ... + '"'`) are two different values. This might help: http://www.northcode.com/blog/String-Literals-vs-String-Values

Comment: @toranzaburo thanks for your advices. 

1) I want to use array because I have couple of objects to hold. 
2) I need string -> value property because I need to get that object with it's title.
3) I need to use like this ['"'+x+'_'+y+'"'] because otherwise it will not be a string and I will have reference error.
4) Yes maybe I should use nested object as you said. Since string values will be different I can use like that.
5) My basic English is bad. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: 1) Arrays are not the only data structure to store objects 2) Then you want a **map** not a list (array). 3) Not correct, `x + '_' + y` already produces a string (what else would the result be? you are doing string concatenation after all). I recommend to read http://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html

Comment: @FelixKling yes actually I need map. I think I should replicate it with object Array combination ?

Comment: Objects are typically used as maps (as the answers are showing). Or literally use `Map` if your environment supports it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need to be reading more about working with objects in JavaScript.

Try [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) first.

```js
var type = "x";
var subType = "y";
var tabsArray = {};
tabsArray[type + "_" + subType] = "z";
console.log("tabsArray = ");
console.log(tabsArray);
console.log("tabsArray['x_y'] = " + tabsArray["x_y"]); // output: z

// Including code added to question as a comment:

var tabsArray = [];
var x = "x";
var y = "y";
tabsArray[x + "_" + y] = "z";
console.log("tabsArray['x_y'] = " + tabsArray["x_y"]);

// tabsArray.length will still be 0. To set .length you can use:
for (var i = 0; i < tabsArray.length; i++) {
    tabsArray.length = ++i;
};
console.log("tabsArray.length = " + tabsArray.length);
```

Comment: hmm why tabArrays is object ?

Comment: @SahinYanlık Have a read through the documentation and you'll know why.

Comment: no no i know what is obj. etc. thanks. Helped me I couldn't remember i can use both dot notion and string for getting element. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely instantiating `tabsArray` as an array, i.e. `var tabsArray = [];`. This results in the observed behavior.

Since you want to define the keys yourself, you should instantiate it as an object instead:

```
var tabsArray = {};
tabsArray['x_y'] = 'z';
```

[More about working with objects in JavaScript.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)